# Initialize LinkedIn Javascript from within Javascript

Tags: javascript, initialization, linkedin-api

Does anyone know how to import the LinkedIn Javascript from within a Javascript file? Basically I want to make a pure js version of this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [API_KEY]
    onLoad:    [ONLOAD]
    authorize: [AUTHORIZE]
    lang:      [LANG_LOCALE]
</script>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Do you have access to jquery?  If so, `$.getScript('//platform.linkedin.com/in.js', function() { ... });`

Comment: I do use jquery, but how would I include the other parameters in that format?

Comment: Previously i could of used what @Tom said and then called `IN.init({api_key: '..' , onLoad: '..' })` but as of recent (within the last few weeks) this doesn't seem to work. Upon closer inspection of the `IN`object the `IN.init()` method doesn't take any arguments though I'm not sure if this was always the case.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate. So it is basically a no go now?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go....

```js
var StackOverflowDemo = {
  apiKey: null;
  getAPIKey: function(){
    if( !StackOverflowDemo.apiKey ){
      alert('Enter in API Key');
      return false;
    }
    return StackOverflowDemo.apiKey;
  },
  onLoad: function(){
    alert('loaded');
  },
  addAccessScript: function(){

      var scriptSrc = '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js';
      var scriptsFound = document.querySelectorAll('script[src="'+scriptSrc+'"]');
      var scriptExists = scriptsFound.length !== 0;
      if( scriptExists ){
        StackOverflowDemo.onLoad();
        return;
      }

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = scriptSrc;

      script.innerHTML = '\n' +
      'api_key:                 '+StackOverflowDemo.getAPIKey()+'\n' +
      'onLoad:                  StackOverflowDemo.onLoad\n' +
      'authorize:               true\n' +
      'credentials_cookie:      true\n' +
      'credentials_cookie_crc:  true\n';

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',StackOverflowDemo.addAccessScript);
```